# Android SDK Crash at android.widget.PopupWindow$1.onScrollChanged(PopupWindow.java:132)

Tags: android

Can someone with google dev team explain how to avoid this crash on pre-ics devices?  In my case an ImageButton on the ListView item is the anchor of the PopupWindow to create a dropdown. I have tried everything popup.dismiss() , popup= null, etc  but nothing seems to prevent this being an issue when the adapter is reset.

I am getting the following exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.widget.PopupWindow$1.onScrollChanged(PopupWindow.java:132)
 05-21 17:02:27.736: E/AndroidRuntime(25836): at   
 android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnScrollChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:607)
```

This Popup is on a list item. Once the last list item is removed from the ListView I resetAdapter to set a footer.  Then when I move away from the screen this error occurs.

Not in Ice Cream Sandwich:  Icecream Sandwich. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/749b0eb2c9a52bb188fd8900859b3725889e0ec0%5E!/

This suggests a fix related to null anchor of PopupWindow.  What can be done?
In my case a button in ListView item is the anchor  of the popup window.
and same issue here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/487

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if OP still needs this since it is half year later that I just saw this..

This is fixed in ICS. However, you may assign a fixed scroll listener via reflection!

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
    try {
      final Field fAnchor = PopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mAnchor");
      fAnchor.setAccessible(true);
      Field listener = PopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mOnScrollChangedListener");
      listener.setAccessible(true);
      final ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener originalListener = (ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener) listener.get(window);
      ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener newListener=
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                    public void onScrollChanged() {
                        try {
                            // PopupWindow implementation has WeakReference<View>
                            WeakReference<View> mAnchor = (WeakReference<View>) fAnchor.get(window);
                            if (mAnchor == null || mAnchor.get() == null) {
                                return;
                            } else {
                               originalListener.onScrollChanged();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
      listener.set(window,newListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }
  }
```

Comment: You put this code where you use have access to the PopupWindow object (where you create/first have access to it, probably your activity class)

Comment: I don't access any PopupWindow in my app but I'm using ActionBarSherlock. 

I read that I need to backport PopupWindow class from ICS to fix this issue, I do it but StateListDrawable class methods are not available, and after backport this class appear more errors that I don´t know how to fix.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/487

Comment: Sorry, you have to look through the source code of ABS to see where it is triggered here. Then you can swap the listener before it pops up.

Comment: Here (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/752) you have more info about this bug